# Javascript click on one element shows it, click on another: hide the first one and show the second

Tags: javascript, onclick, hide, show

I am new here, I try to explain my problem as clear es possible.
I want to make working an index part of a big documentation. I have Buttons or Links (in this case in Example only divs) named from A to Z, and to every letter belongs a bunch of words starting with the chosen letter, like a dictionary.

What I want to achieve: if I click on a letter, the list of words will appear under the buttons. After that I click on another letter, the first activated list will disappear, and appear the next one, and so on.

I have found several explanation on different sites how to show and hide something, and it works already somehow (I must click on the letter again in order to hide it, so my goal was not reached yet), but I did not find a code or tutorial like this one.

Please help, may you have an idea!

My code:

html:

```
    <div onclick="openIndexA()">A</div>
    <div onclick="openIndexB()">B</div>
    <div onclick="openIndexC()">C</div>
    <!-- etc. -->

    <div class="letters" id="A">
        <p>A...1</p>
        <p>A...2</p>
        <p>A...3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="letters" id="B">
        <p>B...1</p>
        <p>B...2</p>
        <p>B...3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="letters" id="C">
        <p>C...1</p>
        <p>C...2</p>
        <p>C...3</p>
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->
```

css:

```
.letters {
    display: none;
}
```

in openIndex.js:

```
function openIndexA() {
  var x = document.getElementById("A");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function openIndexB() {
  var x = document.getElementById("B");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function openIndexC() {
  var x = document.getElementById("C");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
<!-- etc. -->
```

I know, that it is not the best and shortest way to do that, I could loop it through, I've tried it, but till now didn't achieve. I wanted to able to see first, how it works. But if you would have an advice for this, or the whole concept should be changed, please don't hesitate to explain, I am open to learn!.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution and some advice:

```js
function openIndex(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.letters').forEach(elt => elt.classList.remove('active'));
  document.querySelector('#'+id).classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.letters {
    display: none;
}

.letters.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="openIndex('A')">A</div>
    <div onclick="openIndex('B')">B</div>
    <div onclick="openIndex('C')">C</div>
    <!-- etc. -->

    <div class="letters" id="A">
        <p>A...1</p>
        <p>A...2</p>
        <p>A...3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="letters" id="B">
        <p>B...1</p>
        <p>B...2</p>
        <p>B...3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="letters" id="C">
        <p>C...1</p>
        <p>C...2</p>
        <p>C...3</p>
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->
```

For your CSS: Don't work directly on the style, use classes as much as possible.

Here, as you can see, i've added a class `active`. If I add it, it will edit the style.

---

Then, for your JavaScript: if you copy paste more than two times, it's likely you could use a function.

Here, i've done the following: pass the ID you want to activate as a parameter.
Then, i take all the `letters` item and i remove the `active` class. Then, only for the one selected, i add the `active` class.

---

I hope this is clear and will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drwaj5c9/)!

```
var openIndex = document.querySelectorAll('.openindex');
var letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letters');

openIndex.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        letters.forEach(function(e){
            e.classList.remove('show');
        });
        var id = el.getAttribute('data-id');
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add('show');
      });
});
```

and add this css class

```
.show {
    display: block;
}
```